# Tengo Problemas con el CORS en ionic

Tags: php, api, ionic

Estoy realizando una Api con php y mysql en el codgo no tengo un error por ninguna parte pero al correr la aplicacion en Ionic server sale este error.

> access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost/SWsys/SmartWash/Ionicphp/api_rest.php' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Podrian ayudarme a resolverlo?

aqui el codigo de como lo tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Por favor el código **siempre** en formato texto. Un saludo :)

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Echa un vistazo a este post en el blog de Ionic https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 2):

Han pasado ya casi tres años, pero ahora me tocó a mi.

Le estuve dando vueltas y no le encontraba el error hasta que conecte mi dispositivo movil para probar, y me salio ese error de CORS

> access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mihost.com/api/miapi' from origin
> 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

En su día cuando estaba en clase hicimos algo parecido, pero de que nuestro back solo pudiera acceder desde localhost, y como por por no se pierde nada, le metí a mi servidor, el `AllowOrigin` a localhost

```
string[] hosts = new string[ 4 ] {
    "https://mihost.com", 
    "https://localhost", 
    "http://localhost" 
};

app.UseCors( cors => 
    cors.WithOrigins( host )
    .AllowAnyHeader( )
    .AllowAnyMethod( ) 
);
```

> Código de .NET Core 6

Y con eso ya hacia que mi aplicación Android funcionase.
Sería implementar algo parecido en tu backend.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo lo problemas de la cors son muy comunes de lo que parecen, veras las cors son políticas de seguridad de datos, aqui te dejo un enlace por el cual puedes leer y entender mas sobre el tema [Control de acceso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Existe muchas formas de solucionar, ya sea desde el lado del código del cliente o desde el lado del servidor.

Una simple petición de cors desde el lado del cliente podría ser:

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://bar.other/resources/public-data/';

function callOtherDomain() {
  if(invocation) {    
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
    invocation.send(); 
  }
}
```

Esto permite acceder a la sin ningún tipo de restricción, ahora si el sitio a consultar en su htaccess contiene mas políticas de seguridad tendrias que agregarlas antes de el envio, ahora una de las soluciones mas rápida pero poco recomendable es la de incluir un `*` en las politicas, hacer esto permite que cualquier sitio pueda acceder a tus datos ese `*` puede ser reemplazado por tu dirección web, ahora la forma de agregarlo es en htacces lo siguiente:

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```